# How to store returned results from getNumericalCellValue() in Apache-POI library?

Tags: java, apache-poi

So I want to get data from an excel file using the Apache-POI library, that part is already solved, and then store that data in a matrix with corresponding x and y arrays. In my excel file I have my data stored in the following way:

```
x1  y1
x2  y2
.
.
.
xn  yn
```

Here is the method that I wrote to first actually get the data from the excel file:

```
public void getDataFromExcelFile() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            System.out.println("TEST");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

excelFile is a member variable of the class I am writing this method for. Anyways, let's say I have a matrix: with r rows and c columns, for each ordered (x,y) pair of data I have in my excel file, I want to store that ordered pair in a matrix. For example if my first ordered pair was (1,1) I would store that at data[0][0] (let's just assume said matrix is called data).

I looked through the apache-poi documentation thinking that maybe I could treat the getNumericCellValue() method as an array where its 0th index is an x value and its first index is a y-value, but that is not the case. I then tried to use the fact that each individual number returned by getNumericCellValue is its own method return so I tried to establish a counter,i, variable that increase in every iteration - if i is odd then store getNumericCellValue's returned value at the x-column of the matrix, if it is even then store it in the y-value - this approach did not work either. I've been going at this for 3 hours at this point so I figured it was time to ask Stackoverflow. Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: So the main question here is how to store x y coordinates. Hint: An array `double[][] data` is not usable for this. Instead kind of `Point` class is needed for each point. There is [java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) already. All points then can be stored in an array of `Point` or a `List` of `Point`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it to end up working using the point class.